# DriveApp.createFolder creates folder for wrong user

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code is in the onFormSubmit trigger for a Google spreadsheet tied to a Google Form:

```
      var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test 2016 - 2017");
      if (!folders.hasNext()) {
        var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Test 2016 - 2017");
      } else {
        var folder = folders.next();
      }

      var
 docID = DriveApp.getFileById('id').makeCopy('Test Document ', folder).getId();
}
```

When someone uses the link for the form and submits it, this script will create a folder for the owner of the form/spreadsheet - me.

Shouldn't DriveApp be set for the current user?  Am I calling the wrong function?  Is this a Google bug?  Can anyone help?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

this is by design. onFormSubmit triggers run with owner permissions. imagine simply filling a form would give me access to whatever scopes your script has, without you ever authorizing.

Build a webapp instead, and publish it to run as user.

Comment: That makes so much sense...thanks!  I guess it's back to the drawing board for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Access and Permission in DriveApp class.

```
docID.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

References:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This process is creating Staff Evals, so the managers don't want these documents shared with anyone...especially a peon like me.  I need to create the folder and documents in the Drive of the user who is using the form.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being helpful. It is difficult to do it on Google drive.

Comment: Why is it difficult? (it isnt)